# Error ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++

I got this error:

> [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i[1];
    
    int r = 4;
    
    {
        printf("enter a number between 1-10\n");
        while (i != r);
        {
        scanf("%d,&i[0]");
        }
        printf("good job\n :)");
    }
}
```

Comment: `int i[1];` -> `int i = 0;` and `scanf("%d,&i[0]");` -> `scanf("%d",&i);`

Comment: Also, lose the semicolon at the end of the while-line

Comment: Before any solution will do you any good, you must understand the difference between a pointer and an `int`, or indeed between any *Thing* and a *pointer to a Thing.*

Comment: If you call a function, check what it returns. What does `scanf` return?

Comment: `stdio.h` is for c. use `iostream` in c++ instead. also `&i` will suffice you don't need to add array index to it

Comment: Replace i != r with i[0] != r

Comment: It should work (in a defined way), when i[0] is initialized before the while loop?

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that the variable `i` in your code above, is an array of `int` which **decays** to a *pointer to an `int`* due to **type decay**. On the other hand, the variable `r` is an `int`. So when you wrote:

```
while (i != r)
```

this means you're trying to compare a pointer to an `int` with an `int` and hence the said error.

To **solve** this you can use the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = {}; //create an array named arr of size 4 with elements of type int all initialized to 0
    
    //iterate through the array and take input from user 
    for(int &element : arr)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> element; 
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```